# prototype object property created by constructor function in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

In JavaScript, if I create a constructor function **Foo**, a prototype
object will also be created as **Foo.prototype**. So I tried this:

```
function Foo() { this.xx = 1000}
```

I thought the created prototype object **Foo.prototype** will have the
property **xx = 1000**.  So I tried this:

```
console.log(Foo.prototype.xx);
```

But the result is "undefined". Why is this?

Shouldn't there be a Foo.prototype object with single property xx
to be 1000?

Thanks.

Comment: `this.xx` refers to the instance object, not it's prototype...

Comment: Whatever you do in the constructor, it will not be evaluated until you invoke the constructor. Without a `new Foo()`, there will be no `xx` anywhere. And it's not on the prototype either.

Comment: maybe the following answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 0):

If you add the property inside the constructor, each instance will have an own copy:

```js
function Foo1() {
    this.xx = [1000];
}
var foo1 = new Foo1(),
    foo2 = new Foo1();
foo1.hasOwnProperty('xx'); // true
foo2.hasOwnProperty('xx'); // true
foo1.xx == foo2.xx;        // false (each instance has a different copy)
```

You can also use prototypical inheritance. Then, a the same inherited property is shared among all the instances:

```js
function Foo2() {}
var foo1 = new Foo2(),
    foo2 = new Foo2();
'xx' in foo1; // false
'xx' in foo2; // false
Foo2.prototype.xx = [1000];
'xx' in foo1; // true
'xx' in foo2; // true
foo1.hasOwnProperty('xx'); // false (it's inherited)
foo2.hasOwnProperty('xx'); // false (it's inherited)
foo1.xx == foo2.xx;        // true (all instances share the same value)
```

Comment: Thanks oriol for the quick answer. So I guess property xx will always be the property in instantiated object (the object this point to, and not "shared" from Foo.prototype), and Foo.prototype will always be empty to start with ?

Comment: @totally Yes. Well, `Foo.prototype` will contain a non-enumerable `constructor` property with the value `Foo`, and will also inherit from `Object.prototype`.